# Get the name of a ComboBox in ComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, .net

I came across the following problem:

I have a DataGridView with 5 Column where the first 3 are ComboBoxColumns. So i want that a User has to select the first ComboBox so that on the second will be loaded the data (SQL Query with value of first ComboBox). An so on also for the third one which is only working when the first two are set.

Now i have the problem. If I check if selected Index change via the code below. It gives an error because on the second ComboBox i dont need .SubString(). So i wanted to check the names of the ComboBoxes and make some if branches to check wether is the first, second or third ComboBox. But all of my tries give me an empty return.

Is there a possibility to solve my problem?

```
 private void datagridview1_detailed_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
            if (cb != null)
            {
                cb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(selectionchange);
            }
        }

        void selectionchange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;

                //To Test the output
                Console.WriteLine("CB_NAME:" + ((ComboBox)sender).Tag);
                Console.WriteLine("CB_NAME:" + ((ComboBox)sender).Name);
                Console.WriteLine("CB_NAME:" + cb.Name);



                if (cb.Name == "datagridview1_value1")
                {
                    order_id = cb.Text.Substring(0, 6);
                    fill_second_combo();
                }
                else if (cb.Name == "datagridview1_value2")
                {
                    fill_third_combo();
                }
            }
            catch {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }
        }
```

Fill second ComboBox Code:

```
        private void fill_second_combo()
        {
            string rcs = db_conn.connection();

            using (var OraConn = new OracleConnection(rcs))
            {
                using (var OraCmd = OraConn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        OraConn.Open();
                        OraCmd.BindByName = true;

                        OraCmd.CommandText = "select * from xxx where order_id" + order_id +";

                        OracleDataReader OraDataReader = OraCmd.ExecuteReader();
                        if (OraDataReader.Read() == false)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("No data!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            using (var OraDat = new OracleDataAdapter(OraCmd))
                            {
                                using (var combo2_table = new DataTable())
                                {
                                    OraDat.Fill(combo2_table );

                                    foreach (DataRow combo2_row in combo2_table .Rows)
                                    {
                                        foreach (DataColumn combo2 in combo2_table .Columns)
                                        {
                                            if (combo2_row[combo2 ] != null)
                                            {
                                                if (combo2.ColumnName == "Second Value")
                                                {
                                                  
                                                    secondComboBox.Items.Add(combo2_row[combo2.ColumnName].ToString());
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (OracleException ex)
                    {
                        switch (ex.Number)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                MessageBox.Show("F1 -DB Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                break;

                            case 12560:
                                MessageBox.Show("F2 - DB Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                break;

                            default:
                                MessageBox.Show("F3 - DB Error: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Fehlermeldung", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        OraConn.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

All of the Test-Outputs are empty in my case.

Comment: Why do you want to get the "combobox" name, rather than `ComboBoxColumn` name?

Comment: Because i need the name of the ComboBox which triggers the SelectionChanges so i can get the Value from the first one to execute the db query with the value if got from this ComboBox, because my problem is all three ComboBoxes call the same method. so i cannot do SubString because i need this function only when clicking on the first one.

Comment: I highly recommend you create separate, `DataSet\DataTable`’s or `List<T>`s and simply swap out the proper data sources. Manually juggling the values and re-querying the DB each time a combo changes a value seems redundant and unnecessary. How many “different” combinations are there?

Comment: I cant tell you because the value of the ComboBoxes are always changing so it can be sometimes more or less

Comment: This sounds odd… _”ComboBoxes are always changing…”_ ? What is changing them other than the user?

Comment: could you post the code of `fill_second_combo` and `fill_third_combo`. For clarification. So basically you use the selected item from one combobox to use it as filter for a sql query whose results populate the next combobox. am I correct?

Comment: The values that come from a Database are not always the same, so there are sometimes more different combination and sometimes less.

Comment: @Mong Zhu You are right. And the first two values i need in the third one to get the Data from that sql query

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things… … _”so there are sometimes more different combination and sometimes less”_ ? … So what? I agree the number of tables and the number of rows in each table may be different each time, but this is still not preventing you from building the tables as I suggest. This will make swapping out values into one line of code by changing the data source. Again, I am just trying to say that “juggling” the values and re-querying the DB each time a combo changes is not a good approach. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe you can try to get the column index via `dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex` first. Then judge the name based on the index.